# create dynamic image with php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to create image chart dynamically as shown bellow,

[image]

First I tried with php `ImageCreate` but it is hard to manage the space with that.

Then I tried the html5 `canvas` and that is also having a same issue. What I need to know is whether there is an easy way to do html to image conversion. Then I can manage the space easy with other styles.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: define "manage the space" what issues are you having with space?

Answer (score 0):

With [wkhtmltoimage](http://wkhtmltopdf.org) you can convert HTML to an images. You would need a VPS to run it on though. You can then create the HTML and call `wkhtml2image` via PHP to convert the given HTML to an image.

Answer (score 0):

I am creating dynamic image with php with `GDLibrary. [Here](http://surajkumar.in/create-dynamic-image-with-php/) is the script of creating dynamic image.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.